# What's the fastest way to find out how many rows are in a dplyr query?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I typically use dplyr in R to query against my database. Often, when I'm writing my code, I'll want to test if I'm getting a reasonable number of rows. Right now, I do that with:

```
myquery <- dbtable %>%
    filter( foo == 'bar' ) %>%
    select( id, name, address, city, st)

# test to get number of rows (usually done interactively)
myquery %>%
    select(id) %>%
    collect %>%
    nrow
```

This seems like an inefficient way to run--I'm pulling down all those ids just to have R count them. I'm sure the database could do that for me, but I'm not sure how to do it without dropping into pure SQL, which I'd rather avoid. Is there a more dplyr-ish way to do it?

Comment: `%>% summarise(n = n())`?

Comment: Oh, that works nicely (and fast, too!). If you want to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dplyrish way to count rows is with the special function `n()`:

```
myquery %>% summarise(n = n())
```

For the fastest, though, simply grabbing the `dim` or `nrow`, as in @Akbar's answer, is best.

Answer (score 2):

Just use base R functions: `dim(myquery)[1]`